# Manually prioritize overloaded functions

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

I have multiple overloads of the same function. For some set of arguments several overloads fit equally, and I naturally get a "ambiguous overload" error. I want to define priorities to these functions someway such that in case of ambiguity the one with the smallest priority is selected.

I tried to make a series of template helper classes, "tags", `P<0>`, `P<1>`, ..., such that `P<N>` inherits `P<N+1>` with some upper bound. Thus if there are two functions `f(P<2>)` and `f(P<4>)`, and I call `f(P<0>)`, the first one is selected.

It doesn't work in practice. The "clean" example with classic 
"int/long" and "long/int" functions still produces an ambiguity. I tried to add several tag parameters to the function to increase the "weight" of a tag, but it does'n help.

Can this approach be tuned somehow?

```
constexpr static int MAX = 20;

template<int N, class Enable = void>
class P {};

template<int N>
class P<N, typename std::enable_if<N < MAX, void>::type> : public P<N+1> {};

void f(int, long, P<2>) {}
void f(long, int, P<5>) {}

int main() {
    f(1, 2, P<0>());
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use different names for the variants, so you can call the one you want explicitly?

Comment: Why do you need that 'N-1' inheritance? Try with plain version, just `template<int N> class P {};`

Comment: @Barmar Because actually these functions are template ones and generated with this kind of logic: "make a function for all vectors", "make a function for all STL containers", "make a function for all serializable types", etc. And for one type several functions can be generated.

Comment: @ciechowoj If so, P<0> has no way to be converted to P<2>. I don't get you.

Comment: @ciechowoj This is using a well known trick that's often used in tag dispatch; you define a trivial inheritance hierarchy and you use it to rank how preferable different (potentially SFINAE'd) functions are. Often you start the call with the most derived member of the hierarchy. The function taking the most derived class that does not get SFINAE'd out will get called unambiguously. I think though for that tricky to work, a function has to be an unambiguous better match. Here there are implicit conversions at different argument locations, so the functions are not ordered relative to each other.

Comment: @IvanSmirnov have you tried make those overloads templated? [example](https://ideone.com/kwy2OT)

Comment: @IvanSmirnov Sorry, I misunderstood the question at the first time.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all, you can simplify your tag type construction like:

```
template <int N> struct P : P<N+1> { };
template <> struct P<MAX> { };
```

Next, the escalator of tag types only works if they are **the sole** tiebreaker for your overloads. That is, every other argument is equivalent - except the tag argument. The reason your calls are still ambiguous is that the conversion sequences you end up with are:

```
f(int, long, P<2>); // #1: Exact, Integral Conversion, P<0> -> ... -> P<2>
f(long, int, P<5>); // #2: Integral Conversion, Exact, P<0> -> ... -> P<2> -> ... -> P<5>
```

One overload is only better than another overload if, for **each** argument, the conversion sequence is at least as good as the other overload's argument's conversion sequence. That's not true here: `#1` is better in the first argument and worse in the second argument than `#2`. The addition of another argument doesn't change that flaw.

Where the tag types are helpful is if you are using SFINAE with non-disjoint conditions:

```
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<cond_a<T>::value>* = nullptr>
void f(T&&, P<0> ) { ... }

template <class T, std::enable_if_t<cond_b<T>::value>* = nullptr>
void f(T&&, P<1> ) { ... }

template <class T, std::enable_if_t<cond_c<T>::value>* = nullptr>
void f(T&&, P<2> ) { ... }

f(whatever, P<0>{});
```

`cond_a`, `cond_b`, and `cond_c` need not be disjoint, and the first argument in every case is the same. So the final tiebreaker, for those overloads that aren't removed by SFINAE, is the tag.

Comment: Hmm, I really worked a lot with enable_if these days and didn't remember a simple solution for tags :) Thanks, I someway didn't notice that the sequence should be better for each argument, I though it is all about the "total cost of conversion". And your solution fits my problem perfectly, it seems that I overcomplicated the question.

Comment: Thank Barry. I learn a lot from this great answer.  Here is an [MCVE](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa52a8b6b48042fe) after I read this answer.  My sample works for custom class, but not int/long though.